# pass action form object from one action to another

Tags: struts

I have 2 action classes which share the same action form. I have defined the action form in request scope for both of them. Can you please tell me how to transfer this form object from 1st action to 2nd action.

I am avoiding sessions due to IE shares the same session across windows/tabs.

Employee Management app:
When admin edits an employee, it has 3 tabs. Personal, Education, Background.
Each tab represents a separate action class, which all share the common employeeForm action form class. So when admin is on Personal tab, it populates the employeeForm object with all the employee related data. Please tell me how to transfer this object from one tab to another, so that I dont hit the DB again.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1 or Struts 2?

If it's Struts 1.x, then you need to add <html:hidden> tags within the tab's <html:form>, for each of the properties you want to share between tabs.